# Python regex, match group span (start and end)

Tags: python, regex

How can I find the span of a inside group by regex?
I have the following code, but I don't know how to get the span (start, end) of the matched group inside the parentheses:

```
statement = r'new (car)|old (car)'
text = 'I bought a new car and got rid of the old car'
match = re.search(statement, text)
match.span()
Out: (11, 18)
for match in re.finditer(statement, text):
    print match.span()
Out: (11, 18)
Out: (38, 45)
```

In this case for example, I only need to match the span of the 'car' not the whole statement.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to pass [`span`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) an argument:

```
for match in re.finditer(statement, text):
    print match.span(1)
```

1 is referring to the *first* group, the default is zero - which means the whole match.

Comment: It took me half an hour of searching to find this gem... you can run match.span() as well as match.group() rather than searching the string again to get the indices. Gold!

Comment: In case of named groups it is also possible by: `match.span(group_name)`